# 線分(1次ベジェ曲線)を説明する式で、[]が付与されている理由と縦に並んでいる理由は？

Tags: svg

**[Link](http://postd.cc/bezier-curves/)先で、下記式が掲載されているのですが、意味が分かりません。**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

**Q**
・これは座標ですか？
・どうして[]で囲っているのでしょうか？
・どうして縦に並べているのでしょうか？ X,Yのように横に並んでいない理由は？
・これが、バーンスタイン基底関数ですか？
・それとも、二項係数？？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ・これは座標ですか？

はい。二次元座標を表しています。

> ・どうして[]で囲っているのでしょうか？
>   ・どうして縦に並べているのでしょうか？ X,Yのように横に並んでいない理由は？

ベクトルには横ベクトルと縦ベクトルという2つの表し方があります。
ベクトルも行列だと思うと、(1×2)行列か(2×1)行列かの違いです。
ベクトルを横にするか縦にするかは流儀によって異なります。
慣習的に縦か横を決めたり、スペースの都合に合わせて決めたりします。
日本の高校数学だと横ベクトルが多いかもしれませんが、大学数学だと縦のことも多いです。
カッコが [ ] になっているのは、ベクトルのカッコをそう書いているだけでしょう。 (丸括弧でなくても良いというだけです。)

> ・これが、バーンスタイン基底関数ですか？
>   ・それとも、二項係数？？

これは、1次の場合のバーンスタイン多項式に t = 0.5 を代入した形です。二項係数ではありません。

一般のn次バーンスタイン多項式 P(t) は、制御点が P₀, P₁, …, Pₙ とあったときに、下の式で表されます。ただし ₙCᵢ は二項係数です。

[image: 一般のバーンスタイン多項式です]

「バーンスタイン基底関数」は、上の式で赤い下線を引いた部分のことです。
バーンスタイン多項式はバーンスタイン基底関数と制御点を掛けて足したもの（つまり、線型結合したもの）になっています。

これに n = 1 を代入すると、記事にもあるように、1次の場合のバーンスタイン多項式が出てきます。

[image: n = 1 のときのバーンスタイン多項式の導出です]

上の式は t をパラメータとした多項式であり、0≦t≦1 のとき、図形としては線分 P₀P₁ を表しています。
たとえばこの式に t = 0.5 を代入すると、質問文の中に書いてある 0.5(P₀ + P₁) という式が出てきます。

また、上と同様に n = 2 の場合を求めると、2次の場合のバーンスタイン多項式、つまり、(2次)ベジエ曲線の式が導出できることが分かると思います。

Comment: 「バーンスタイン多項式はバーンスタイン基底関数と制御点を掛けて足したもの（つまり、線型結合したもの）」。この説明が分かりやすかったです。最初数式を見て「うわ」と思ったのですが、 n に色々代入した具体例を提示いただいたので、ようやく何をやってるか分かりました。大変参考になりました！

Answer (score 2):

> ・これは座標ですか？
>   ・どうして[]で囲っているのでしょうか？

単純に行列です。１ｘ２行列ですから座標といってもいいです。

> ・どうして縦に並べているのでしょうか？ X,Yのように横に並んでいない理由は？

結局のところ座標を表示したいだけなので、１ｘ２行列でも２ｘ１行列でもよいわけです。
リンク元ページ作者は１ｘ２行列で表記しただけです。
あなたが気に入らないなら１ｘ２でも２ｘ１でも、お好きなほうでどうぞ。

Answer (score 2):

リンク先で言うP<sub>0</sub>, P<sub>1</sub>は、いわゆるベクトルです。
点（座標）Ｐをベクトルで表して
原点Ｏから点P<sub>0</sub>へのベクトル
→
OP<sub>0</sub>を略して

→ →
P<sub>0</sub>,P<sub>1</sub>

→を略して

P<sub>0</sub>,P<sub>1</sub>と言ってます。

線分
＿＿
P<sub>0</sub>P<sub>1</sub>をP<sub>0</sub>からP<sub>1</sub>へのベクトルとすると、

→
P<sub>0</sub>P<sub>1</sub>は、

ベクトルP<sub>1</sub>－ベクトルP<sub>0</sub>

P<sub>1</sub> - P<sub>0</sub>で、
中間の点は
（基点とするベクトルP<sub>0</sub>）＋(P<sub>0</sub>からP<sub>1</sub>へのベクトル)×比率(リンク先ではt)
まとめると
P<sub>0</sub>＋(P<sub>1</sub> - P<sub>0</sub>)t
P<sub>0</sub>(1-t)＋(P<sub>1</sub>)t
(1-t)P<sub>0</sub>＋tP<sub>1</sub>となります。

ベクトルP<sub>0</sub>をいわゆるデカルト座標系(x-y座標)であらわすと、
P<sub>0</sub>＝（P<sub>0x</sub>, P<sub>0y</sub>)
P<sub>1</sub>＝（P<sub>1x</sub>, P<sub>1y</sub>)
となって、
(1-t)P<sub>0</sub>＋tP<sub>1</sub>をこちらで書き直すと
((1-t)P<sub>0x</sub>+tP<sub>1x</sub>, (1-t)P<sub>0y</sub>+tP<sub>1y</sub>)
tが0.5の時
(0.5(P<sub>0x</sub>+P<sub>1x</sub>), 0.5(P<sub>0y</sub>+P<sub>1y</sub>))
になります。

> ・どうして[]で囲っているのでしょうか？

[ ]で囲っているのはこれが行列表現だということだと思います。

> ・これは座標ですか？

中間の点を(x,y)座標表現にして行列で表現したものですので、座標（中間点へのベクトル）です。

> ・どうして縦に並べているのでしょうか？ X,Yのように横に並んでいない理由は？

表現としては縦でも横でもいいですが、
おそらく、
例えば、２元１次方程式などを行列表現するときに、

```
ax+by=c
Ax+By=C
```

を

```
|a b||x| |c|
|   || |=| | 
|A B||y| |C|
```

のように書かれることが多いので、それにならったものだと思われます。

> ・これが、バーンスタイン基底関数ですか？

「バーンスタイン基底関数」についてよく知りません。
これが一番単純な形の「バーンスタイン基底関数」なんですかね？よくわかりません。

> ・それとも、二項係数？？

既に説明した通りで、中間点の座標を表現しています。
「[二項係数](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%8C%E9%A0%85%E4%BF%82%E6%95%B0)」ではありません。

Comment: 「リンク先で言うP0, P1は、いわゆるベクトルです」。これはベクトルなのですね、全く気が付きませんでした。「中間点」の算出式詳細も、参考になりました